# is there any syntax for non-recursive binding in Haskell, just like the difference between `let` and `let rec` in similar languages?

Tags: haskell

Non-recursive binding allows me to shadow bound value, for instance:

```
b a = let norec a = a + 10 in a
```

here `let norec` created by myself means a `let` binding but not recursive.

This is extremely helpful when using record wildcards:

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord{ {- vary huuuuuge set of definitions -} }

foo MyRecord{..} = let norec field1 = field1 + 1
                             field2 = modify field2
                             {- some other modifications to the fields -}
                    in MyRecord{..}
```

Is that achievable? Or how do you deal with it in your cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are record wildcards actually that useful here? The usual old way of doing things looks quite concise to me:

```
foo r = r { field1 = field1 r + 1, field2 = modify (field2 r) }
```

The direct answer to your question is that there is no non-recursive analog of `let` in Haskell; though you can use the `Identity` monad to sort of hack something into place:

```
foo MyRecord{..} = runIdentity $ do
    field1 <- return (field1 + 1)
    field2 <- return (modify field2)
    return MyRecord{..}
```

Answer (score 4):

> is there any syntax for non-recursive binding in Haskell

No, there is no way to refer to a previously defined variable of a given name while defining a new variable with the same name.

> ```
> foo MyRecord{..} = let norec field1 = field1 + 1
>                              field2 = modify field2
>                              {- some other modifications to the fields -}
>                     in MyRecord{..}
> ```

This can be achieved by spelling the modified fields out explicitly (while still covering the unchanged ones with the wildcard). Since you don't need local variables that way, it isn't even more code:

```
foo MyRecord{..} =
  MyRecord {
    field1 = field1 + 1,
    field2 = modify field2,
    ..
  }
```

Note that here the identifier left of the equals sign is a record label, not a variable, while the on the right side is a variable, so even though this looks recursive, it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question, but I'd like to point to the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) alternative. Lenses are really quite a good solution to the problems of Haskell's records, which become quite a pain with larger data definitions and which `RecordWildcards` does, alas, not really fix as nicely as we'd like.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH (makeLenses)

data MyRecord = MyRecord{ _field1 :: ...
                        , _field2 :: ...
                        {- note the underscores -} }
makeLenses ''MyRecord

foo = (field1 %~ (+1))
    . (field2 %~ modify)
    . ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
-- also available from the lens package
(&) :: a -> (a->b) -> b
(&) = flip ($)

f a = -- let norec a = a + 1 in a+a
      (a+1) & \a -> a + a

g x = -- let norec x = x+1 in
      (x+1) & \x ->
      -- let norec x = x+x in
      (x+x) & \x -> 
      -- 1000+x
      1000+x
```

Not terribly elegant, but at least it's concise. It will also generate a few "shadowing" warnings.