# Why do I get an exception loop

Tags: haskell

I tried following expression in prelude:

```
let x = x in x
```

and I've got following exception

```
Exception: <<loop>>
```

Why is the expression recursive?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Configure it out, why do I got an exception?

Comment: Because all `x` are the same above.

Comment: BTW this exception is a "favor" from the runtime, telling you that it caught what would otherwise be an infinite loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any syntax for non-recursive binding in Haskell, just like the difference between \`let\` and \`let rec\` in similar languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816937/is-there-any-syntax-for-non-recursive-binding-in-haskell-just-like-the-differen)

Comment: Why wouldn't the expression be recursive? What non-recursive meaning could there be for this?

Comment: I'm confused why you think it would  **not** be an infinite loop. What you've said is that `x` is equal to `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`let` bindings in Haskell are (mutually) recursive, meaning that you can refer to any of the defined variables/functions (things to the left of the `=` signs) in any of their definitions (the stuff to the right of the `=` sign). For the case where you have arguments (functions), this is pretty much always the intuitive expected behaviour.

```
let fact n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1) in fact 5
```

In the above, you probably are not surprised that `fact (n - 1)` can be used in the definition of `fact n`. In your example, you are using `x` in its own definition.

When Haskell tries to evaluate `let x = x in x`, it keeps trying to expand `x` (into the RHS `x`) hence the loop.